# Populating ListBox in Userform with each element of an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, listbox, userform

I have the following problem: In one module I created an array "arArray" with values from a specific column. Each value of said array represents a weeknumber based on another dataset. The array is defined in another module as Public under Option Explicit. This works perfectly. Below the code for the array.

```
Dim arrayData   As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim Row_Count As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastRow2 As Long

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import")
lastRow2 = sh.Columns(45).Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

Set arrayData = sh.Range("AS2:AS" & lastRow2)

arArray = sh.Range("AS2:AS" & lastRow2)

Row_Count = arrayData.Rows.Count

   
For i = 1 To Row_Count

  
    arArray(i, 45) = Cells(i, 45).Value

Next i
```

Now I'm trying to fill all values of "arArray" into the Listbox "Lst_Tabellen" of the UserForm "Auswertung". Below the code for Initialization:

```
Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()



With Lst_Tabellen

Lst_Tabellen.Clear


Lst_Tabellen = arArray

End With


End Sub
```

I'm calling this userform in another sub:

```
Public Sub Call_Userform()

Auswertung.Show


End Sub
```

My problem is, that the Userform opens, but without any values. I never programmed a userform before, so I'm really stuck here. Can you guys see my error?

Comment: Did you try: `Lst_Tabellen.List = arArray` in the `Initialize` code?

Comment: Thanks a lot. That actually solved my problem!